# karma/jasmine tests are not going into the it blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I basically followed these instructions:

http://ericnish.io/blog/set-up-jasmine-and-karma-for-angularjs

to set up karma with jasmine. I set up the example test and I am getting this result:

`Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)`

To debug it, I put an alerts into the example test like this:

```
describe('example test', function() {
    alert('example!');
    it('should be true', function() {
        alert('example in it caluse!');
        expect('foo').toBe('foo');
    }); });
```

and I only see the `alert('example!');` not `alert('example in it caluse!');`

---

addedum:

I sort of figured out what is going on -- or at least a superficial part of the puzzle. It turns out that this weird behavior only happens when I have angular-scenario.js included -- i was able to do this:

```
   exclude: [
        'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-scenario.js'
    ],
```

to work around the issue -- but still mysterious why this would be!

Comment: same goes for `beforeEach` clauses ... the function registered with it never get's called

Comment: Why are you even using [Angular Scenario Runner](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/e2e-testing)? Given that it's API identical to Karma, I'd say it's simply overwriting all the Karma methods (describe, beforeEach, it, etc)